# WINDBG doing strange jumps in source code

Tags: debugging, vb6, windbg

I have a windows service that was written in VB6 that I want to attach to and debug in WINDBG.

The service is compiled without optimizations (also all boxes in "Advanced Optimizations" are unchecked), and "Create Symbolic Debug Info" is checked. I have the source file of a class I want to set breakpoints in. I can set breakpoints on some lines but not all... even though the lines where I can't put a breakpoint at don't have anything exotic, simple variable assignments and such.

Regardless, the breakpoints I can set are hit when I run the service with the `g` command, but when I start to "step over" (F10), the code does some strange leaps and doesn't (or at least doesn't appear to) evaluate all lines...

It seems to me that the source file and the symbols file are out of sync, but I just compiled the project and moved the files over to the computer where I want to debug... What could cause the source files and the pdb/dll file of the project to be out of sync?

Comment: Hmm, it seems VB6 becomes popular again ... Symbols of VB6 are not very good. So you copied the PDBs and DLLs to the target PC? Have you tried `!sym noisy` in WinDbg, `symchk` (separate tool, comes with WinDbg) or [chkmatch](http://debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html)? Also, check `lmf` in WinDbg to see where the DLL is loaded from. Maybe there's a copy of the DLL used from a place you're not aware of.

Comment: This environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Always have the right symbols. Also CoClassSyms (http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.

Comment: Here's what I did: @Noodles suggestion seemed more general so I went with that first. I set the env and compiled. Moved the DLL, which was significantly heavier, to the target machine. When I attached to the process, the symbols for the DLL were automagically loaded, which at the time I thought was absolutely sexy. Inspected the loaded modules; said CodeView in "Symbols". Tried to set breakpoint, and oh no... "Code not found, breakpoint not set". Re-compiled without `/pdb:none`, went and performed a check with chkmatch... Matched. Reattached. Set breakpoints. Works... what? :/